# не могу разобраться с nginx location

Tags: nginx, location

подкинули проект.пытаюсь его развернуть.yii2 advanced.
скинули два файла конф-и для Nginx. Один подключается к другому.
все работает кроме перехода в админку(/admin).Подскажите куда копать.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.sjecproject.fvds.ru sjecproject.fvds.ru;
    return 301 https://sjecproject.fvds.ru$request_uri;
}

server {
    # listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sjecproject.fvds.ru/sjec.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sjecproject.fvds.ru/sjec.key;
#    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name         www.sjecproject.fvds.ru;
    return 301 https://sjecproject.fvds.ru$request_uri;
}

server {
    # listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sjecproject.fvds.ru/sjec.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sjecproject.fvds.ru/sjec.key;
#    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name         sjecproject.fvds.ru;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/sjecproject.fvds.ru.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/sjecproject.fvds.ru.error.log;

    root /var/www/sjecproject.fvds.ru;
    index index.php;

#    include snippets/restrictions.conf;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml image/svg+xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    location ~* ^.+\.(rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|rtf|js|css|woff|woff2|svg)$ {
        expires max;
    }
    include snippets/yii.conf;
}



#yii.conf;
# Yii2 single site rules.
# Designed to be included in any server {} block.

location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
        log_not_found off;
}

# Deny access to any files with a .php extension in the uploads directory
# Works in sub-directory installs and also in multisite network
# Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to fail2ban for ex.)
#location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
#    deny all;
#}


location / {
    # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
    # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.(php)$ {
    #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Comment: Добавить `location /admin { ... }` или использовать адрес `/admin/index.php`. Как вариант - использовать `rewrite`

Comment: @Total Pusher Спасибо за ответ.Переход по пути /admin/index.php не работает с текущими конфигами.Подскажите как правильно написать rewrite. Читаю документацию, и не пойму куда и как впихнуть директиву корректно

Comment: Странно, что `/admin/index.php` не срабатывает. Он должен подпадать под `location ~ \.(php)$`. Вот посмотрите как сделано для [Докувики](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/dokuwiki/), если не сможете, я напишу.

Answer (score 0):

РЕШЕНО!там был файл с текстом "../../backend/web"...оказывается в прошлом это была символьная ссылка.проблема решена вводом команды

```
ln -s ../../backend/web /var/www/sjecproject.fvds.ru/frontend/web/admin
```